# wso2 esb json to json converting double quotes missing

Tags: json, proxy, wso2, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I have a problem in converting json to json in wso2 esb, actually I'm using payload factory in a proxy and I call the proxy with rest and json content. Here is my integration flow, I call a proxy and the proxy sends the request(with json content) to a jms message store then, I defined a message processor to consume messages from message store and send them to a defined endpoint(.net web api). but the problem is strings with numbers automatically get converted as integer elements: "orderId": 10000 ( I want it to be string "orderId": "10000") , but when I send the request directly from proxy to my end point (without using message broker) it works correctly. Could you please help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more details refer to [my question with more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38321898/wso2-esb-json-missing-quotes-and-brackets-when-using-scheduld-forwarding-message/38327388#38327388) on this problem, and looks like this is a bug in wso2 esb 4.9.0
[wso2 jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4750)

Answer (score 0):

For your problem need to change a JSON Message Formatters.
please follow the below steps for that.

- change your working directory to [ESB Home]/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
- then you need to change JSON Message Formatters instead of JsonStreamFormatter use org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter.

> ```
>   <!--messageFormatter contentType="application/json"                                class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/-->
>     <messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
>                               class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONStreamFormatter"/>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following builder and formatter in axis2.xml

```
org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder
org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter
```

Remove existing builder and formatter for the "application/json" and add the below.

Add under Formaters section

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                          class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
```

Add under Builders section

```
 <messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                            class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
```

Comment: I did this before, but nothing happens, could you please take a look at my new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38321898/wso2-esb-json-missing-quotes-and-brackets) , I've explaint my problem with much more details. thanks